# How to make sure AssemblyLoadContext would use Load to get all the assemblies from scratch?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, plugins, .net-7.0

I have type `A` implementing interface `IA` from assembly `aA.dll`. It creates *K* instances of type `B` from `aB.dll`. I want to get `A` from `aA.dll` to use type `B` from `bB.dll` which is same  in its name and version to `aB.dll` yet with minor code differences. So I try:

```
    public class CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext
        : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        public CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext() : base(isCollectible: true)
        { }

        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
        {
            string path = "";
            if (AssemblyNameToPath.TryGetValue(assemblyName.FullName, out path))
            {
                return Assembly.LoadFile(path);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Yet when I try to create a A as IA using:

```
    public static object GetRaw<T>() where T : class
    {
        AssemblyLoadContext context = new CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext();
        var type = typeof(T);
        Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyName(type.Assembly.GetName());

        Type programType = assembly.GetType(type.FullName);
        object result = Activator.CreateInstance(programType);

        return result;
    }
```

Generally `X` is what I get while `V` is what I want from this [picture](https://assets.ctfassets.net/9n3x4rtjlya6/7eA83FDPnEQ4jPyLX7eQYj/23144face7a433c303ee045d3e585f96/100788_279808118_Raffaele_Rialdi_An_in-depth_look_at_the_new_features_in_C_8.0_and_.NET_Core_3.0.pdf):
[image]

Type `B` is used from preloaded in general context `aB.dll`. How to make it load if from `bB.dll`? How to make sure AssemblyLoadContext  would use Load to get all the assemblies from scratch, not only one?

A small [demo project](https://github.com/OlegJakushkin/TestAssemblyLoadContextAfterCecil) we tried to test it with, yet it fails to load more than one assembly deep no matter what...

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge different versions of DLLs / dependencies are not allowed in the same AppDomain. So a type can only resolve to one DLL in the same ApPDomain. Spinning up a new AppDomain might be what you can try.